# C Можно ли сократить код?

Tags: c

Требуется написать свой Bruteforce т. е. пользователь вводит какой-то пароль и программа методом перебора всех возможных вариантов находит этот пароль. Предполагается, что программа не может отработать и не найти пароль. Ограничение перебора осуществляется пользователем, т.е  будут ли включены в перебор цифры, заглавные буквы, символы и т. д.

Рекомендую ограничить длину вводимого пароля до 4-х символов, больше не надо, иначе программа долго будет работать. Еще лучше, если на этапе разработки программы, длина пароля будет 2 — 3 символа. Кроме того, задайте в программе множество допустимых символов пароля. Например, в пароле могут использоваться только цифры и/или буквы, это заметно поможет ускорить процесс отладки программы-брутфорса.
Задание взято с http://cppstudio.com/post/8059/comment-page-4/#comment-3414

Хотел узнать можно ли как-то сократить мой код?

```
/*
 *  by biggy 
 *
 *  Bruteforce 
 */ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void yyy(void);
void nyy(void);
void nny(void);
void yny(void);
void yyn(void);

int main (void)
{

    char y1 = 0, y2 = 0, y3 = 0;

    printf("Will you use characters (y/n) ?");
    scanf(" %c", &y1);
    printf("Will you use big characters (y/n) ?");
    scanf(" %c", &y2);
    printf("Will you use numbers (y/n) ?");
    scanf(" %c", &y3);


    if(y1 == 'y' && y2 == 'y' && y3 == 'y') yyy();
    else if(y1 == 'n' && y2 == 'y' && y3 == 'y') nyy();
    else if(y1 == 'n' && y2 == 'n' && y3 == 'y') nny();
    else if(y1 == 'y' && y2 == 'n' && y3 == 'y') yny();
    else if(y1 == 'y' && y2 == 'y' && y3 == 'n') yyn();

    printf("done.");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void yyy(void)
{
    char buffer[5] = {0};
    char buffer2[5] = {0};

    printf("Enter your password ?");
    scanf("%4s", buffer);

    for(char i = '0'; i != '}'; ++i)
    {
        for(char j = '0'; j != '}'; ++j)
        {
            for(char u = '0'; u != '}'; ++u)
            {
                for(char z = '0'; z != '}'; ++z)
                {
                    if(i == ':') i = 'a';
                    else if(i  == '{') i = 'A';

                    if(j == ':') j = 'a';
                    else if(j  == '{') j = 'A';

                    if(u == ':') u = 'a';
                    else if(u  == '{') u = 'A';

                    if(z == ':') z = 'a';
                    else if(z  == '{') z = 'A';

                    buffer2[0] = i;
                    buffer2[1] = j;
                    buffer2[2] = u;
                    buffer2[3] = z;

                    //printf("%s\r\n", buffer2);
                    if(strcmp(buffer, buffer2) == 0)
                        printf("Your password: \t%s\r\n", buffer2);

                    if(z == 'Z') break;
                }
            if(u == 'Z') break;
            }
        if(j == 'Z') break;
        }
    if(i == 'Z') break;
    }

    return;
}

void nyy(void)
{
    char buffer[5] = {0};
    char buffer2[5] = {0};

    printf("Enter your password ?");
    scanf("%4s", buffer);

    for(char i = '0'; i != '}'; ++i)
    {
        for(char j = '0'; j != '}'; ++j)
        {
            for(char u = '0'; u != '}'; ++u)
            {
                for(char z = '0'; z != '}'; ++z)
                {
                    if(i  == ':') i = 'A';

                    else if(j  == ':') j = 'A';

                    else if(u  == ':') u = 'A';

                    else if(z  == ':') z = 'A';

                    buffer2[0] = i; buffer2[1] = j;
                    buffer2[2] = u;
                    buffer2[3] = z;

                    //printf("%s\r\n", buffer2);
                    if(strcmp(buffer, buffer2) == 0)
                        printf("Your password: \t%s\r\n", buffer2);

                    if(z == 'Z') break;
                }
            if(u == 'Z') break;
            }
        if(j == 'Z') break;
        }
    if(i == 'Z') break;
    }

    return;
}

void nny(void)
{
    char buffer[5] = {0};
    char buffer2[5] = {0};

    printf("Enter your password ?");
    scanf("%4s", buffer);

    for(int i = 48; i < 58; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 48; j < 58; ++j)
        {
            for(int u = 48; u < 58; ++u)
            {
                for(int z = 48; z < 58; ++z)
                {
                    buffer2[0] = i;
                    buffer2[1] = j;
                    buffer2[2] = u;
                    buffer2[3] = z;

                    //printf("%s\r\n", buffer2);
                    if(strcmp(buffer, buffer2) == 0)
                        printf("Your password: \t%s\r\n", buffer2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

void yny(void)
{
    char buffer[5] = {0};
    char buffer2[5] = {0};

    printf("Enter your password ?");
    scanf("%4s", buffer);

    for(char i = '0'; i != '}'; ++i)
    {
        for(char j = '0'; j != '}'; ++j)
        {
            for(char u = '0'; u != '}'; ++u)
            {
                for(char z = '0'; z != '}'; ++z)
                {
                    if(i  == ':') i = 'a';

                    else if(j  == ':') j = 'a';

                    else if(u  == ':') u = 'a';

                    else if(z  == ':') z = 'a';

                    buffer2[0] = i; 
                    buffer2[1] = j;
                    buffer2[2] = u;
                    buffer2[3] = z;

                    //printf("%s\r\n", buffer2);
                    if(strcmp(buffer, buffer2) == 0)
                        printf("Your password: \t%s\r\n", buffer2);

                    if(z == 'z') break;
                }
            if(u == 'z') break;
            }
        if(j == 'z') break;
        }
    if(i == 'z') break;
    }

    return;
}

void yyn(void)
{
    char buffer[5] = {0};
    char buffer2[5] = {0};

    printf("Enter your password ?");
    scanf("%4s", buffer);

    for(char i = 'a'; i != '}'; ++i)
    {
        for(char j = 'a'; j != '}'; ++j)
        {
            for(char u = 'a'; u != '}'; ++u)
            {
                for(char z = 'a'; z != '}'; ++z)
                {
                    if(i  == 'z') i = 'A';

                    else if(j  == 'z') j = 'A';

                    else if(u  == 'z') u = 'A';

                    else if(z  == 'z') z = 'A';

                    buffer2[0] = i; 
                    buffer2[1] = j;
                    buffer2[2] = u;
                    buffer2[3] = z;

                    printf("%s\r\n", buffer2);
                    /*
                    if(strcmp(buffer, buffer2) == 0)
                        printf("Your password: \t%s\r\n", buffer2);
                    */
                    if(z == 'Z') break;
                }
            if(u == 'Z') break;
            }
        if(j == 'Z') break;
        }
    if(i == 'Z') break;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста опишите словами, что делает ваш код?

Comment: пожалуйста опишите алгоритм по которому происходит кодирование. если возможно, то дайте ссылку на стандарт. добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: `Рекомендую ограничить длину вводимого пароля` — это кто кому рекомендует? Выглядит как будто вы скопировали сюда то, что вам написал преподаватель. И весь этот абзац — на каких данных лучше отлаживать код — не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу.

Comment: http://cppstudio.com/post/8059/comment-page-4/#comment-3414

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь учить C, самостаятельно, выполняя разные задания. Я на програмиста не учусь. Мне просто нравится програмировать!

Comment: Достойное занятие. Кроме шуток! У меня программирование тоже не профессия :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да запросто :) - например, так, как показано ниже. Я не стал использовать какой-то из приличных алгоритмов генерации всех кортежей, просто потому что у нас всего 4 цикла и не более, так что просто сделал их вложенными...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char * bigAl = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char * digit = "0123456789";

int main (void)
{
    char y = 0;
    char syms[128] = {0};
    int found = 0;
    char passw[5] = { 0 };
    char guess[5] = { 0 };

    printf("Will you use characters (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &y);
    if (y=='y') strcat(syms,alpha);

    printf("Will you use big characters (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &y);
    if (y=='y') strcat(syms,bigAl);

    printf("Will you use numbers (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &y);
    if (y=='y') strcat(syms,digit);

    if (strlen(syms))
    {
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        scanf("%4s", passw);
        for(char * c = syms; !found && *c; ++c)
        {
            guess[0] = *c;
            guess[1] = 0;
            if (strcmp(guess,passw) == 0)
            {
                found = 1; break;
            }
            for(char * c1 = syms; !found && *c1; ++c1)
            {
                guess[1] = *c1;
                guess[2] = 0;
                if (strcmp(guess,passw) == 0)
                {
                    found = 1; break;
                }
                for(char * c2 = syms; !found && *c2; ++c2)
                {
                    guess[2] = *c2;
                    guess[3] = 0;
                    if (strcmp(guess,passw) == 0)
                    {
                        found = 1; break;
                    }
                    for(char * c3 = syms; !found && *c3; ++c3)
                    {
                        guess[3] = *c3;
                        if (strcmp(guess,passw) == 0)
                        {
                            found = 1; break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Password = [%s]\n",(found) ? guess : "NOT FOUND");
    printf("done.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Кстати, для 4 символов в самом худшем случае перебирается менее 15 миллионов символов, так что не вижу никакого смысла выяснять, есть ли там большие буквы или нет, например - уж такое количество все равно проверится на современной машине почти мгновенно...

Comment: Я знаю. Но старался делать по заданию

Comment: Всеравно спасибо!

Comment: Кстати перебор только больших или маленьких символов не работает по вашему коду.

Comment: И если ввести пароль к примеру `aZZZ` (маленькие и большие символы) то ваша программа ломается. Мне кажется потому что у вас первий цикл сразу выходит если нашел совпадение. Может переместить `if (strcmp(guess,passw) == 0) { found = 1;  break; }` ниже в цикле?

Comment: Как ломается? Что это значит? Не находит? А вы ответили `y` на использование и букв, и больших букв? Смотрите сами: http://ideone.com/4xHyu2

Comment: Да. Просто пишет `done. ` без ответа

Comment: Когда вы пишете что-то типа - *Кстати перебор только больших или маленьких символов не работает по вашему коду.*, давайте конкретный пример. Введено то-то, получено то-то.

Comment: Еще раз - посмотрите http://ideone.com/4xHyu2 Сами видите, что пишет найденный пароль. Вы точно верно перенесли код и дали правильный ввод? Тем более что ПРОСТО `done`, **без ответа** программа просто не может вывести! Строчка `Password =` просто обязана присутствовать - смотрите код сами...

Comment: Уже все работает правельно)). Извините! Может компилятор баловался, реально ломалась прога.

Comment: А если ещё подумать, то можно вполовину сократить наверняка.

Comment: @0andriy Дерзайте :) Поскольку последовательность рефакторинга ограничена снизу и монотонно убывающая - у нее есть предел. Есть к чему стремиться :)

Comment: Мне-то зачем? Пусть топик стартер тренируется. ;)